# Java stream: use optional filter() operations on chaining

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, predicate

Note: this question is **not** related to `java.util.Optional`.

When dealing with streams, I often use logic like this:

```
 Stream<FooBar> stream = myInitialStream();
 if (needsFilter1) stream = stream.filter(c -> whatever1());
 if (needsFilter2) stream = stream.filter(c -> whatever2());
 ...
 return stream.collect(toList());
```

What I am trying to achieve is converting the code above to a single-expression using chaining. I find this more readable and straight forward.
Until now, the only way I found to achieve that was:

```
return myInitialStream()
       .filter(needsFilter1? c->whatever1() : c->true)
       .filter(needsFilter2? c->whatever2() : c->true)
       .collect(toList());
```

Still, this would make unnecessary calls to those trivial `c->true` lamdas, which might produce some performance cost when scaling up.

So my question is: is there a better way of producing chained stream expressions that include optional filtering?

UPDATE: Maybe I did not make it clear enough, but the point of my question is finding a **single-expression solution**. If I have to use multiple statements (to initialize a predicate, for example), I could also use the first code-block of my question which essentially does the same.

Comment: is either `needsFilter1` or `needsFilter2` always guaranteed to be true?

Comment: No, these conditions are not related to each other, they can be whatever. Also, the filter operations that I need to perform are not always two. I just listed two to keep the post shorter, but could be more. I am searching for a pattern that would work no matter how many filterings you want to perform.

Comment: You could go with something like public static <T> Predicate<T> conditionalFilter(boolean condition, Predicate<T> filter) {
  return condition ? filter :  o -> true;
 } The method is generic (does not have to be rewritten all the time) and could be static-imported.

Comment: @Michal this is for sure more elegant as a syntax, but still, the o->true is being unnecessary called.

Comment: How do you determine whether or not the filter is needed? Can the filters themselves be aware and simply return true if not needed?

Comment: You could do `.filter(c->(needsFilter1 && whatever1())` which is shorter and more readable than your ternary expression, and hope the JIT will realise that `needsFilter1` is a constant (or unchanging) expression and optimise it out.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thanks for the answer. This has indeed much more elegant syntax than my second solution, but the performance consideration still remains, might be even a bit worse if the JIT cannot optimize that extra AND instruction...
What I really need if a function that would return the stream unchanged, or a new stream that is the old one filtered by the "whatever" condition. Looks like this is not possible...

Comment: to be clear, are you trying to avoid multiple if blocks? or multiple filters? @AlkisMavridis

Comment: I am trying to avoid multiple statements. I try to perform optional filtering within a chained stream expression, but without unnecessary trivial calls to o->true.

Comment: In my opinion the performance is more influenced by the streaming and collecting rather then by repeated calls of c -> true. At the same time, the streaming / collecting cannot be avoided for the requirement 'one chained call' and 'Java streamimg API'.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou If you do `.filter(c->(needsFilter1 && whatever1())` and `needsFilter1` is `false`, you'd end up with a predicate that returns `false` for all elements of the stream. Clearly, this is wrong, because OP wants to skip filtering in this case.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner good catch! I meant `.filter(c->(!needsFilter1 || whatever1())`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou in which case the JIT would have to optimize one NOT + one OR instruction inside the lamda... Maybe it the ternary is preferable, after all, since its evalutaion happens once, outside of lamda..

Comment: @AlkisMavridis Do you have some way to match `boolean` values and predicates? I mean, do you have them in some sort of structure? Or are they just variables that you use based on some name pattern? And how many pairs are we talking about here?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner unfortunatelly not. All conditions and filters are independent from each other. Actually my post is a template of situations that I often find myself. I was hopping to find a general pattern for that, but it looks like there is none...

Comment: By the way, worrying about the overhead of a call to `.filter(c->true)` is a bit academic when you consider that `.collect(toList())` is O(N log N).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chain the predicates according to the conditions using [`Predicate::and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) returning a new Predicate.

```
Predicate<FooBar> predicate = c -> whatever();

if (condition1) { predicate = predicate.and(c -> whatever1()); }
if (condition2) { predicate = predicate.and(c -> whatever2()); }

List<FooBar> dest = list.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Upon an update requesting a single expression. You **need** a source of mapped conditions to predicates anyway. With the data structure `Map<Supplier<Boolean>, Predicate<Integer>>`, where a key is a `Supplier` of a condition deciding whether a value (`Predicate<FooBar>`) shall be used.

Reduce the entries of a map to a new `Predicate<FooBar>` using chaining these `Predicates` with [`Predicate::and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html), for which their `Supplier<Boolean>` returns `true` (the condition is valid).

Having a `Map` of the conditions:

```
Map<Supplier<Boolean>, Predicate<FooBar>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(() -> needsFilter1, c -> whatever1());
map.put(() -> needsFilter2, c -> whatever2());
...
```

Here is a single `Stream` statement:

```
List<Integer> dest = list
        .stream()
        .filter(map.entrySet()                            // filter with a predicate ...
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getKey().get())            // .. where a condition is 'true'
                .map(Entry::getValue)                     // .. get Predicates
                .reduce(i -> true, (l, r) -> l.and(r)))   // .. reduce them using AND
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why would not want to have the predicate created this way? I mean single expression statements are fine for simple actions but here you attempt to create a predicate that changes dynamically based on various conditions. Not only using single expression statements effectively hides the multiple unneeded calls, but furthermore it also makes the whole thing a bit more unreadable. Why don't create a method that accepts the flags and returns the constructed predicate? If not this way you'll also achieve better re-usability (assuming that you use the said predicate elsewhere).

Comment: As mentioned, I use this kind of logic very often with different combination of filters. Having to every time write helper methods with flags that return the predicate would not help me. If there is no way to have a single-expression solution, I would go with the first code block of my question, which is fine, but not ideal. In any case, my question is whether there is a way to achieve this. If this is a good idea or not is a rather subjective matter.

Comment: @AlkisMavridis: Not fully, yet this is a correct approach which doesn't leave the `Stream` opened and avoids temporal coupling between the `Stream::filter` calls. You want to construct a predicate to be applied once, here I provided *one* of those ways.

Comment: @Nikolas What I ask for is a single-expression solution. I am sorry if I have not stated that clear enough, but this is precisely what my question is about. Your solution is a nice approach and thank you for posting it, but it does not answer my question.  Maybe what I ask for is simply not possible in java-stream API, which is maybe the answer.

Comment: @Nikolas thanks a lot! This now is genius idea. So as I understand your approach, I could work with maps or collections to build my stream. Those would provide the conditions and filters to be used. In the worst case, I would have the overhead of one o->true filtering, but this would be just one.  Also the filter() part could go in an utils function that would be written only once and used everywhere. Looks great to me!

Comment: Instead of `.map(Entry::getValue).reduce(gobbledygook)` can't you just do `.allMatch(Entry::getValue)`?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: Nope, the idea of reducing `Predicate`s is to chain them using `Predicate::and` method to result **one** predicate to be used in the `Stream::filter`. The method `Stream::allMatch` returns `boolean` which is not helpful here.

Comment: `Map` is a very inconvenient collection to fill in in a one-line manner (Java 9's `Map.of` simplified it a bit, though).

Comment: I think you `filter` stuff should be moved into a method because it looks cumbersome and unmaintainable now. Anyway, I like the idea, pretty similar to mine.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Yes Andrew, for sake of brevity and the OP's request, I included such a single-statement approach. I prefer to use objects even for the smallest procedures.

Comment: Instead of `Supplier<Boolean>` you can use `BooleanSupplier`. Further, instead of `.reduce(i -> true, (l, r) -> l.and(r))`, you can use `.reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(i -> true)` which saves you from combining existing predicates with `i->true` (in fact, you’ll get the original predicate if only one remains, then).

Answer (score 4):

I am a bit late with my solution, anyway I'll leave it here.

I had an idea of writing a builder to construct a complex `Predicate` but ended up with a class `FilterCondition` and a method `FilterCondition.combine`.

```
Stream.of("123", "1", "12345", "", "12", "", "2")
    .filter(FilterCondition.<String>combine(
                FilterCondition.of(() -> true, s -> s.contains("3")),
                FilterCondition.of(() -> true, s -> s.contains("2")),
                FilterCondition.of(() -> false, s -> s.isEmpty())
            ).toPredicate())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With the static import of `FilterCondition.of` and `FilterCondition.combine,` it would look even better.

```
Stream.of("123", "1", "12345", "", "12", "", "2")
    .filter(combine(
                of(() -> true, s -> s.contains("3")),
                of(() -> true, s -> s.contains("2")),
                of(() -> false, String::isEmpty)
            ).toPredicate())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`FilterCondition<T>` is basically a `Predicate<T>` with an extra condition for checking whether the `predicate` should be applied.

`FilterCondition.combine` takes some `FilterCondition`s and makes up a combined one.

```
class FilterCondition<T> {
    private final Supplier<Boolean> filterEnabled;
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;

    private FilterCondition(Supplier<Boolean> filterEnabled, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.filterEnabled = filterEnabled;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public static <T> FilterCondition<T> of(Supplier<Boolean> filterEnabled, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return new FilterCondition<>(filterEnabled, predicate);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> FilterCondition<T> combine(FilterCondition<T>... conditions) {
        return new FilterCondition<>(
                () -> true,
                Arrays.stream(conditions).filter(i -> i.filterEnabled.get()).map(i -> i.predicate).reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(t -> true)
        );
    }

    public Predicate<T> toPredicate() {
        return predicate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Shall `FilterCondition` implement `Predicate<T>`? Cons: The method `get` would be implemented against an interface contact. Flexible using variety of constructors. The object would **be** a predicate, not just provide it. What do you think? Have my +1 for a nice way :))

Comment: @Nikolas what kind of `Predicate`'s constructors did you imply?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Noone. Predicate is a functional interface. I meant that your custom class would be flexible using more constructors.

Comment: @Nikolas what constructors? Could you give an example?

Comment: I think what @Nikolas means is that you can generate a Predicate instance using the lambda syntax. It is technically not a constructor, but it acts similarly to a constructor.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko By the way, your solution is precisely what I was looking for. I find its logic very similar to the Nikolas answer above. Also, building a class with methods such as combine / toPredicate is a really great way to implement this kind of logic in an elegant and reusable way. Thanks!

Comment: FilterCondition looks like the Builder pattern, but with a different syntax to the way most Java builders work.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes, but I think `combine` is a good replacement for the `builder().and(...).and(...).build()` style

Comment: @AlkisMavridis to represent a `FilterCondition` by a lambda, it should be a functional interface (an interface with a single method), but it can't be such since it holds the state of 2 fields.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, sorry, I misread... Sure, for your FilterCondition class is very good as it is. You could not replace it with a functional interface.